# Unable to render Django app with Jelastic

Tags: python, django, jelastic

I want to render my Django with jelatic.

I cloned my Django app on jelastic.
[image]

I configured my Postgres database and modified my settings.py so that my app is connecting to my database.

[image]

Finally to render my app I run this in the SSH : python manage.py runserver
And everything seems to work :

[image]

But I get this response on my browser:

[image]

Any help will be appreciated =)

Comment: Python apps are expected to run via WSGI on Jelastic. Please post your wsgi.py file (also see https://jelastic.com/blog/django-cms-installation-python-cloud-hosting/ for some tips how to deploy an existing Django app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i found out how to modify apache server file to put your own django web app on Jelastic solution:

Go to the file : /etc/httpd/conf.d/wsgi.conf

Do these modification:

```
#----------  Put this in comment line ----------

#Alias /images /var/www/webroot/ROOT/images
#Alias /static /var/www/webroot/ROOT/static

#WSGIScriptAlias / ${WSGI_SCRIPT}
#WSGIProcessGroup apache

#----------  Add those code line ----------


WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/mysite.com/mysite/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonHome /path/to/venv
WSGIPythonPath /path/to/mysite.com

<Directory /path/to/mysite.com/mysite>
<Files wsgi.py>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Files>
</Directory>

Alias /media/ /path/to/mysite.com/media/
Alias /static/ /path/to/mysite.com/static/

<Directory /path/to/mysite.com/static>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Directory>

<Directory /path/to/mysite.com/media>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 1):

The thing is that as we can see the site is started manually on the localhost (127.0.0.1) and on port 8000.  Then there is a try to open the domain from the outside (despite the fact that the application is listening only on 127.0.0.1 localhost and only on port 8000). Obviously, nothing is opened in response because Apache is listening on port 80, which is not configured to work with this application (and the application itself is also not accessible from the outside).
In order for Apache + mod_wsgi to work successfully with this application, the application is not needed to be started manually as was done before, but it is needed to write a wsgi entry point similar to what is described here https://jelastic.com/blog/django-cms-installation-python-cloud-hosting/ (point 6 of manual installation).